# A custom scroller that actually uses scroll, not animate?

Tags: javascript, scroll

Im looking for a way to scroll the content of a div, whitout animating the content, but instead actually scrolling the div.

Preferably, the result would be something like this:
http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

but when you drag the handle, i want the div containg the long content to scroll, not the long content to animate in to view.

I would like to do this because that would mean the content is scrollble on touch devices aswell, and it would utilize the browsers scroll-capabilities instead of moving dom-objects around.

I found this script http://jsfiddle.net/Nkf9n/18/ wich lets you scroll by dragging, with added inertia, but i cen't really wrap my head around how i would apply i to a separate handle, controlling the scrolling.

jquery-solution would be ok, but i'd prefer a vanilla-javascript example to wrap my head around.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/ ?

Comment: Hm, not really, although it seems interesting. It seems to use css transistions for the scrolling, instead of animation style properties, which is nice, but i need a way to controll the scrolling with a sepreate handle.

Comment: What I'm lloking for is something like what you get here http://campaign.tetrapak.com/productxplorer/ (click "Packages" in the bottom menu, then "Tetra Brik Aseptic" and the "Tetra Brick Aseptic" link in the top of the menu)

Comment: Much better with an example --'
I really like the Dragdealer (pure JS): http://code.ovidiu.ch/dragdealer/. You can use its API to control the DIV with the items. Check the file http://code.ovidiu.ch/js/dragdealer-main.js to see how they use the "animationCallback" method in the second example (Vertical).

Comment: Thank you very much, looks easy enough to apply to the scroll-property instead of animating styles!